# Can rpm package build on Fedora be used on other systems?

Tags: fedora, rpm

I want to build rpm package for my icon theme and upload it to www.gnome-look.org, with deb and tar.gz. If I'll build it on Fedora will users be able to use it on other systems like Red Hat?

The package don't have any binaries only few shell scripts and svg files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I'll build it on Fedora will users be able to use it on other systems like Red Hat?

Yes. If you provide only non-binary content. And if you will use compatible paths and compatible RPM macros for RHEL. If I remember well, for example `%doc` does not work in older RPMs.

Comment: `%doc` works in all but very, very, very old versions of RPM. Some things like `%license` are more recent.